# STFP Connection and Downloaded confusion

Tags: php, phpseclib

Been trying to connect Filezilla and my website together via PHP and SFTP is proving to be tedious.

How do you connect with STFP, the information online is very brief for the most part, I have downloaded the SSH2.php file and have used the code that is included in the file (the Test File) and it does not work. The page does not load, an error message is displayed due to the use of the SSH2 functions I suspect.

Connection

```
// Connect to FileZilla
include("../model/connection.php");
$con = new SFTPobj();
$connect =  $con->serverConnection();
```

Test File:

```
Class SFTPobj{
function serverConnection()
{
    include('../controller/SSH2.php');
    $server = "xx";
    $user = "xx";
    $pass = "xx";  
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
        if (!$ssh->login( $user, $pass)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
    echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
    echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
}
```

}

Test File- * code (irrelavant for the most part):

```
    <?php
    // Connect to database
    include("../model/connection.php");
    $con = new SFTPobj();
    $connect =  $con->serverConnection();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
            print_r($file);

        $fileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileTmpName=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize=$_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileError=$_FILES['file']['error'];
        $fileType=$_FILES['file']['type'];

        #only allow images
        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        #Image types
        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg', 'png');

        #Check file type
        if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed))
        {
            if($fileError === 0)
            {
                if($fileSize < 500000) #500KB
                {
                    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt; #Random Number Generate
                    $fileDestination = '../view/pictures/week1'.$fileNameNew;
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
                    header("Location:../view/test.php?uploadSuccess");
                }else{
                    echo "Your file is too big";
                }
            }else{
                echo "There was an error uploading your file";
            }
        }else{
            echo "You can not upload files of this type";
        }



    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your file:

```
include('../controller/SSH2.php');
```

In the zip file download SSH2.php is in the Net/ directory. There's also a Crypt/ directory and a Math/ directory. Both of those are needed and the relative path's need to be correct as well.

The fact that you've taken SSH2.php out of the Net/ directory makes me think you may not have the other requisite files. And even if you do I'm skeptical that they're in the right relative location.

Also, since you appear to be using the 1.0 branch, you may need to set the include_path to get it to work properly, depending on where you place the directory:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include('Net/SSH2.php');
?>
```

Really, I'd just recommend *against* picking and choosing the files you think you need. Just take the entire phpseclib zip file and dump it into the phpseclib file.